# ActiveX calling Javascript functions

Tags: c++, plugins, activex, atl

I am trying to call Javascript from my ActiveX (ATL C++) dll.  From the research I have done you should connection points.

Added to my idl file

```
[
uuid(BDBFA5F9-B2CB-43b1-A414-CB6E3B15C6C2),
("Event interface for Test")
]
_ITestEvents
    {
    properties:
    methods:
    [id(1), helpstring("method Cancel")] void Cancel([in] char* x, [in] char* y);
    };
```

Added to my class .h file

```
class ATL_NO_VTABLE CTest :
public CComObjectRootEx<CComSingleThreadModel>,
public CComCoClass<CTest, &CLSID_Test>,
public IConnectionPointContainerImpl<CTest>,
public CProxy_ITestEvents<CTest>,
public IObjectWithSiteImpl<CTest>,
public IObjectSafetyImpl<CTest,INTERFACESAFE_FOR_UNTRUSTED_CALLER | INTERFACESAFE_FOR_UNTRUSTED_DATA>,
public IProvideClassInfo2Impl<&CLSID_Test, &__uuidof(_ITestEvents), &LIBID_Test3Lib>,
public IDispatchImpl<ITest, &IID_ITest, &LIBID_Test3Lib, /*wMajor =*/ 1, /*wMinor =*/ 0>
    {
    public:


    BEGIN_COM_MAP(Clnaxprt)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY_IMPL(IConnectionPointContainer)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(Ilnaxprt)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IDispatch)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IConnectionPointContainer)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IObjectWithSite)
        COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IObjectSafety)
        COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IProvideClassInfo)
        COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IProvideClassInfo2)
    END_COM_MAP()

    BEGIN_CONNECTION_POINT_MAP(Clnaxprt)
        CONNECTION_POINT_ENTRY(__uuidof(_ITestEvents))
    END_CONNECTION_POINT_MAP()
```

In visual studio "implemented a new connection point" which generated code in the _ITestEvents_CP.h that was created with a method name Fire_Cancel( char * x,  char * y). And that is where I am stuck. I have tried to call the Fire_Cancel and when debugging the generated code there are no connections and thus no Invoking from IDispatch. What do I do to create a connection?

Still not sure how the javascript works yet but want to get this part understood before I move to that.
Thanks

Comment: I have found some tutorials on connection points, which I have implemented but I'm not sure how this allows me to talk to JavaScript. Since when the event fires I have no connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML and Javascript in my case were wrong. If your using the notation "id::function_name" make sure it is afterthe object tag. If the notation is "for=id event=cancel" then it can be located before/after

Comment: how is your HTML look like? How do you implement the JS handler and how do you hook it up to the event?

Comment: Well I'm am sure I pulled this from somewhere on stackoverflow.com And I am almost sure taxillian had given the answer. But my JavaScript references the id of the ActiveX in the Html. HTML Example: <embed id="plugin" type="application/myplugin">. JS example: <script for="plugin" event="myActiveXMethod()">alert("hello");</script>. The myActiveXMethod is going to be an event in your ActiveX. Hope this is what you were looking for.